# iOS - Displaying traffic on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, google-maps

I know how to display routes/overlays onto a map view. I tried to check if there was an API for traffic on the iOS 5 Google Maps or iOS 6 Beta Apple Maps but its not available.

Both maps (google and apple) are capable of displaying traffic on the map view as a route form. I am looking to mimic that. Is there an API I can use, or particularly a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe the data from Google Traffic is public. There are some valid answers here on this Quora post: http://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-public-API-for-obtaining-traffic-information

You will most likely have to find out that information yourself and that add it to your map, colorized if you like (as the maps app does on your iOS Device).

Hope that helps.